# native c++ thread name does not display in visual studio thread window when debugger is attached after the thread is named

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio, winapi, visual-studio-debugging

Our application follows [these instructions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcb2z8hs.aspx) to set the name of a thread in native c++ on windows.

The thread names display fine in the thread window of visual studio if you attach before the thread names are set, however if you attach after the thread names are set then you just see some default name "msvcr120d.dll".

Is there any way to ensure that the thread names will display regardless of when you attach?

Comment: I'm not particularly familiar with the setThreadName function, but from your question I guess that it's not possible. However, why not attach the debugger before the thread is created? You can put a DebugBreak() statement just before the thread is created.

Comment: Don't think this is possible due to the way Microsoft implements their thread naming feature. See this blog post for more info: https://ofekshilon.com/2009/04/10/naming-threads/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thread objects in the Windows OS do not have a name. Naming threads is purely a feature of the debugger. The code to 'set' a thread's name raises an `MS_VC_EXCEPTION`, that's caught by the debugger, and the information used for the debugging experience. If no debugger is present, the exception filter simply continues execution.

In other words: You cannot have named threads, unless you attach a debugger **before** calling the `SetThreadName` function as per [How to: Set a Thread Name in Native Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcb2z8hs.aspx).

Comment: I suspected this was the case, but it didn't seem to be documented anywhere. Thanks!